# How to write 'a signal should never have certain value before it attains some other value' in SystemVerilog assertion?

Tags: system-verilog, verification, systemverilog-assertions

I would like to write the following in SVA (SystemVerilog Assertion) format.

`signal a should never be 2 until it attains the value 1`

How can we do that?

Comment: Sorry, I cant help it, this triggers immediately: *"Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three."*

Comment: ... *Five is right out!*

Comment: For the clueless: http://www.montypython.net/scripts/HG-handgrenade.php

Answer (score 5):

```
property p;
  @(posedge clk) (A != 2) until (A == 1);
endproperty

assert property (p);
```

Comment: Another related question: I want to generate the counter-example for this property. When I try `assert property (not(p))` for that purpose, it says syntax error. Is there an issue with using `not` with `until`?

Comment: Another doubt: How can I write the following in SVA?
`not(a until b)` without using `until` or `s_until`.

Comment: You cannot use parenthesis `()` with property expressions.

Comment: Okay. What would be the recommended way if we want to negate such a property? The objective here is to get the counterexample corresponding to the property (hence the negation).

Comment: Assert property ( not p)

Answer (score 2):

Such a condition requires a state machine, and cannot be done with simple assertions alone. You need to build the state machine, and then make an assertion that certain transitions cannot occur within that state machine.

Comment: Do you mean state machine in the Verilog design or state machine in the SVA property (is that possible)?

Comment: I just showed a very simple assertion.